# Hanami : access current page URL from views or templates

Tags: ruby, hanami, hanami-router

I'm discovering Hanami those days (Hanami 1.3), I'm polishing the test project I've worked on, and I can't find a way to **access the current page url/path from a view or a template** (the idea is handling the navigation links visual state, as you may have guessed).

I've tried to guess helper names (`routes.current_page`, `routes.current_url`, `routes.current`...) but I've not been lucky. I've checked the [routing helpers documentation](https://guides.hanamirb.org/helpers/routing/), got through the [hanami/hanami](https://github.com/hanami/hanami) and [hanami/router](https://github.com/hanami/router) repositories but didn't find what I was looking for.

Did I miss something or is this simply not built-in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing, for the moment. I followed [hanami documentation](https://guides.hanamirb.org/helpers/custom-helpers/) defined a custom helper and made it available to all of my views, like this:

**1. Create a `Web::Helpers::PathHelper` module**

There I can access the params and request path:

```
# apps/web/helpers/path_helper.rb
module Web
  module Helpers
    module PathHelper
      private

      def current_path
        params.env['REQUEST_PATH']
      end

      def current_page?(path)
        current_path == path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**2. Make sure the helpers directory is loaded by the app**

Added the `helpers` path to the application `load_paths` variable, so that my helpers get loaded when the app loads the code.

```
  # apps/web/application.rb
  # Relative load paths where this application will recursively load the
  # code.
  #
  # When you add new directories, remember to add them here.
  #
  load_paths << [
    'helpers',
    'controllers',
    'views'
  ]
```

**3. Make sure my new helper is available for each view**

..by using the `view.prepare` block in `application.rb`:

```
  # apps/web/application.rb
  # Configure the code that will yield each time Web::View is included
  # This is useful for sharing common functionality
  #
  # See: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/hanami-view#Configuration
  view.prepare do
    include Hanami::Helpers
    include Web::Assets::Helpers
    include Web::Helpers::PathHelper
  end
```

**4. And now I can use my helpers in every view!**

And now, from my template or my view objects, I can access my own `current_path` and `current_page?(path)` helpers, and do what I need to do with them. I don't know if that's the most straightforward way but at least it's working.

Comment: You did a great job! Yours is a perfect example of asking the community, read the docs, gets the hands dirty, implement a great solution, and share back with the community. 

Comment: Thanks @LucaGuidi. Hope it can help the community. Maybe it could even be an opportunity for a PR or an hanami extension. I'm not familiar enough with the framework, the codebase and all but that's an idea.